# Equivalent to 'SELECT * FROM tbl' in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am often using a subset of a subset of a `data.table` and it would often be great to just be able to somehow select all columns from the initial subset and then just add the new columns calculated in the second subset, basically a direct equivalent of using an `*` in a SELECT statement in any SQL DBMS.

```
d <- read.table(text="Fuel     Year   Region   Count
Gasoline 2013       GE  169600
                Diesel   2013       GE   46790
                Hybrid   2013       GE    2268
                Electric 2013       GE      85
                Other    2013       GE     532
                Gasoline 2013       VS  149232
                Diesel   2013       VS   50591
                Hybrid   2013       VS    1028
                Electric 2013       VS     268
                Other    2013       VS     261", header = TRUE)


d <- data.table(d)
```

One possibility is to use a `:=` assignment in the second subset `[]` and then add a third level of squared brackets `[]`.

```
 # Example with one additional column
 d[, .(ct = sum(Count)), by=Fuel][, s := ct/sum(ct)][]
 # Example with two additional columns
 d[, .(ct = sum(Count)), by=Fuel][, `:=`(s1 = ct/sum(ct)
                                         ,s2 = ct/sum(ct)+1 )][]
```

Is there any possibility to achieve the same result by using some kind of placeholder for all columns from the previous table?

Comment: Re your `d <- read.table(); d <- data.table(d)` idiom, you might want to look at `fread`. I'm not sure I understand your question, but `d[, .(ct = sum(Count)), by=Fuel][, \`:=\`(s1 = s1 <- ct/sum(ct), s2 = s1+1 )][]` is somewhat simpler.

Comment: Thanks @Frank, the question is not so much about the coding itself, this is just an example. I find it to be kind of weird that one has to use the `:=` operator, although nothing is actually assigned, to be able to automatically select all columns from the first subset.
For me it would make more sense to do something like:
`d[, .(ct = sum(Count)), by=Fuel][, .( $arbitrary_wildcard_operator
                                          , s1 = ct/sum(ct)
                                         , s2 = ct/sum(ct)+1)]`

Comment: I just found out that `dcast` is using something like this. There it's possible to use `...` on the LHS of the formula.
`DT <- data.table(v1 = rep(1:2, each = 6),
                 v2 = rep(rep(1:3, 2), each = 2),
                 v3 = rep(1:2, 6),
                 v4 = rnorm(6))
dcast(DT, ... ~ v3, value.var = "v4") #same as v1 + v2 ~ v3, value.var = "v4"`
Would it make sense to add that to the basic `data.table` functionality?

Comment: Fyi, when pasting multiple lines into a comment, you can put `;` between them so the code can be run by others when copy-pasted. I'm not sure I follow. I think the intention from the start was to let separate functions dcast+melt handle reshaping, instead of integrating them into `[.data.table`. If you want to argue for the latter, you could file a feature request.

Comment: For me, `:=` exactly does what you are asking for, It implies to take all columns of the data.table and to add the additional columns (or replace if already existing). So, the funcionality is there. If you like, the `:` of `:=` is the equivalent of the SQL `*`.

Comment: Also, `data.table` focuses on speed and therefore tries to avoid copying the whole stucture. `:=` is meant to change a `data.table` _by reference_.

Comment: @UweBlock, although the problem is, that without the additional `[]`, the sole usage of `:=` doesn't give any output if the assignment works, since it's silent. 
If it works for everybody else, then there's not an issue, although I would prefer some additional wildcard, which would select all remaining columns of a data.table, like `...` in the `dcast` case. Additionally I don't see, how my question is related to speed, since I don't talk about copy anything.